# JavaScript ES6 in super function stop sub function

Tags: javascript, inheritance, ecmascript-6

So I was wondering if this is possible.  I want the super() function to stop the sub() from continuing.

```
class Parent(){
   foo(){
        //Stop command that stops the code here.
   }
}

class Child extends Parent{
   foo(){
        super().foo();
        //this code should not run
   }
}
```

I know I can have the parent return false and test for it, but then all my children would have to test for it.  One of the reasons to use inheritance is to move common code to the parents.  I don't think this is possible (or even advised) but I was just wondering.

Comment: Throw an exception?

Comment: What if you pass the Child logic as a parameter to the Parent? Then you could do the checking inside the parent class and determine if/when to run the child code? Example: `foo(func) => { ... }` called like `super.foo(() => { ..child logic..});`

Comment: Please specify your use case. If you want to stop execution on errors, just throwing an exception should do the trick. Otherwise, probably you are using a bad coding pattern.

Answer (score -1):

why you are not call direct parent class method using **__proto__**

```
class Parent{
   foo(){
        //Stop command that stops the code here.
   }
}

class Child extends Parent{
   foo(){
        super.foo();
        //this code should not run
   }
}

var c = new Child();
c.__proto__.__proto__.foo();
```

Comment: a) because `__proto__` is deprecated b) because that doesn't call a method on the `c` instance